# Integral of the square of Brownian motion using definition of variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma, geometric-brownian

Let $B = \{ B(t); t \ge 0\}$ and let $Z = \{ Z(t); t \ge 0  \}$ where $$Z(t) = \int_0^t B^2(s) ds.$$ How do we find $E[Z(t)]$ and $E[Z^2 (t)]$ in order to get the variance $Var [Z^2(t)] = E[Z^2 (t) ] - E[Z(t)]^2$

There have been a number of posts similar to this question [Variance of time integral of squared Brownian motion](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/variance-of-time-integral-of-squared-brownian-motion),
[Distribution of time integral of Brownian motion squared (where the Brownian motion occurs in square root time)?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/distribution-of-time-integral-of-brownian-motion-squared-where-the-brownian-mot) and [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time)
but they all involved using ideas that are not available to me yet, i.e., Ito lemma and symmetry etc.

My question is that is it possible to solve the problem using definition of variance by finding $E[Z^2(t)]$ and $E[Z(t)]^2$ without necessarily using ito? I would be glad if any one helps me out.

Comment: Let me have a shot at half of it:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z_t]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t B^2(s) ds\right]=\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[B^2(s)] ds=\int_0^t s ds=[0.5s^2]_0^{t}=0.5t^2$$

Above, I used the fact that expectation is an integral and the order of integration can be changed (the conditions for being able to change the order of integration are in Fubini's Theorem: we don't need to go there).

$$Z_t^2=\int_0^tB^2(s)ds\int_0^tB^2(h)dh$$ 

Now with $\mathbb{E}[Z_t^2]$, I am not sure how to proceed. Let me have a think about it (and I will happily take an advice from more experienced users here...).

Comment: Note that $$Z_t^2 = \int_0^tB^2_sds\int_0^tB^2_hdh = \int_0^t\int_0^t B_s^2B_h^2dsdh.$$ You can use Fubini again.

Comment: @JanStuller. Whiles you think about the second piece, could you throw more light on $E[B^2(s)] = s ?$

Comment: @holala: $B(s) = B(s) - B(0) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, s-0)$, where $B(0) = 0$ by definition of Brownian Motion, and $s$ is the variance of Brownian Motion increment. Then $B(s)^2 = (B(s)-B(0))^2 = \mathcal{N}(0, s)^2$, and expectation of zero mean normal variable squared is the variance.

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz. Could you please refer me to any theorem about the expectation of zero mean normal variable is the variance?

Comment: @holala: it should expectation of a zero mean normal variable *squared*. The proof is  $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ then $\sigma^2=Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[(X-0)^2] = E[X^2]$.

Comment: Oh ok. That's right

Comment: @Gordon: I understand  your "Note that" part and Pontus explanation of how $B^2_{s}$ is the variance but can you do the rest of the integral so hard heads like me can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon: Suppose $h>s$, then:

$$W_h^2=(W(h-s)+W(s))^2=W(h-s)^2+2W(h-s)W_s+W_s^2$$

So:

$$W_s^2W_h^2=W_s^2W(h-s)^2+2W(h-s)W_s^3+W_s^4$$

Taking the expectations:

$$\mathbb{E}[W_s^2W(h-s)^2]=s(h-s)$$

$$\mathbb{E}[2W(h-s)W_s^3]=0$$

$$\mathbb{E}[W_s^4]=3s^2$$

Then:

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^t W_s^2 W_h^2 ds dh\right]=\int_0^t \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^2 W_h^2] ds dh=\int_0^t \int_0^t sh-s^2+3s^3 ds dh=\\=\int_0^t  \left[0.5s^2h-\frac{1}{3}s^3+\frac{3}{4}s^4\right]_0^t dh=\int_0^t  0.5t^2h-\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{3}{4}t^4 dh=\left[0.25t^2h^2-\frac{1}{3}t^3h+\frac{3}{4}t^4h\right]_0^t=\\=\frac{3}{4}t^5-\frac{1}{12}t^4$$

Comment: PS: @Gordon: I would in fact be interested in the interpretation of
$$\int_0^tW_hdh\int_0^tW_sds=\int_0^t\int_0^tW_hW_sdhds$$
Riemann integral of $W_t$ is just a random area: so I suppose the double integral is a random 3D object? Also, how does this link to a two-dimensional Brownian motion (i.e a vector): does an integral of a two-dimensional Brownian motion exist? Is it well defined? Would it represent the same thing, i.e. a random 3D object? I'd be happy to raise this as a standalone question, if others are also interested in this / if the answer merits a standalone thread.

Comment: @JanStuller: For a given sample $\omega$, the integrals are for continuous functions and are thus can be changed to a double integral. Only when you are taking the expectation, the random part is involved. There are no two-dimensional Brownian motions involved here, given that W_s and W_h, for given $\omega$, are from the same continuous function, but evaluated at different time point.

Comment: @Gordon: so for a given $\omega$, the double integral would nonetheless be an area squared = volume?

Comment: @JanStuller: You can treat it  as a volume, but it is not an area squared. In general, $$\int_a^b dy \int_c^d f(x, y) dx = \int_a^b \int_c^d f(x, y) dx dy,$$ for which you can treat it as the volume over the rectangle $[a, b]\times[c, d]$, but with the top surface $f(x, y)$.

Comment: @JanStuller. careful, the integrand should be $sh-s^{2}+3s^{2} = sh+2s^{2}$

Comment: @ChristopherK: you're correct. I cannot amend the comment, but I see you've written out the correct solution below.

Answer (score 1):

As per the hint, you first write

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left [\left (\int_{0}^{t} W_{s}^{2}\, ds \right )^{2} \right ]
&= \mathbb{E} \left [\left (\int_{0}^{t} W_{s}^{2}\, ds \right )\left (\int_{0}^{t} W_{u}^{2}\, du \right ) \right ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds \right ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds \right ] + \mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{s}^{t} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds \right ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds \right ] + \mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{u} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, ds \, du \right ] \\
&= 2\mathbb{E} \left [\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds \right ] \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} \mathbb{E}[W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}]\, du \, ds.
\end{align*}

Now calculate (for $u<s$)
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W_{u}^{2}W_{s}^{2}] &= \mathbb{E}\left [W_{u}^{2} \left ((W_{s}-W_{u})^{2} + 2W_{u}(W_{s}-W_{u}) + W_{u}^{2}  \right )\right ] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[W_{u}^{2}]\mathbb{E}[W_{s-u}^{2}] + 2\mathbb{E}[W_{u}]\mathbb{E}[W_{s-u}] + \mathbb{E}[W_{u}^{4}] \\
&= u(s-u)+3u^{2} \\
&= 2u^{2} + us.
\end{align*}

Your answer will then be
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left [\left (\int_{0}^{t} W_{s}^{2}\, ds \right )^{2} \right ] 
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} \mathbb{E}[W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}]\, du \, ds \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} 2u^{2}+us \, du \, ds \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \frac{7}{6}s^{3}\, ds \\
&= \frac{7}{12}t^{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your rational for rewriting $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^t W_s^2 W_h^2 du ds\right]$$ as $$2\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^s W_s^2 W_h^2 du ds\right]$$ ? The expectation can already be put inside the integral at the first step...

Comment: You can split it up into $$\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du \, ds$$ and $$\int_{0}^{t} \int_{s}^{t} W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}\, du\, ds$$ if you'd like and integrate (you would verify that they are the same). But your $$\mathbb{E}[W_{s}^{2}W_{u}^{2}] = 2\min\{s,u\}^{2} + su$$ so you still need to break up into two triangles to integrate.

Comment: True, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the variance is due to our benevolent contributors.
$$\begin{align*} 
\mathrm{Var} [Z^2(t)] & = \mathrm{E} \ [Z^2 (t) ] - \mathrm{E}\ [Z(t)]^2 \\
& = \mathrm{E}\  \left [\left (\int_{0}^{t} B_{s}^{2}\, ds \right )^{2} \right ] - \mathrm{E}\ \left[\int_0^t B^2(s) ds\right]^2\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} \mathrm{E} \ [B_{s}^{2}B_{u}^{2}]\, du \, ds - \left(\int_0^t \mathrm{E}\ [B^2(s)] \right)^2 ds\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{s} (2u^{2}+us) \, du \, ds - \left([0.5s^2]_0^{t} \right)^2\\
&= \frac{7}{12}t^{4} - \frac{1}{4}t^4\\
&= \frac{1}{3}t^{4} .
\end {align*} $$